# how does rails route know model errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following [this tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-links) to learn ruby on rails and they did the following in the controller:

```
def new
  @article = Article.new
end

def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'new' #<--
  end
end
```

if you see the line where I have the arrow, the logic is, if there is an error in saving a new article, I should `render 'new'` (which hits the `new` route?) and renders the form again so I can resubmit after fixing errors.

my question is, how does the new route know what the errors were? Is there something happening in the background that sends over the error when `@article.save` fails?

I'm confused because the new route creates a new Article object and sends it to the view, how are errors preserved?

here's the 'new' view:

```
<h1>
    file thing add
</h1>
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>

<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When ActiveRecord's `save` method is called, it attempts a save with your datastore. a successful save will return the updated model/object itself (truthy). an unsuccessful save attempt will return false AND add an `errors` property to your object.

Essentially you are saying

```
if the article saves successfully
  redirect to the article's SHOW action (in rails router talk)
else
  redirect to the article NEW action
```

in either case your @article instance variable will persist, but in one case it is sending you back a step with a handy `errors` array to work with.

Comment: wait, Uzbekjon said it doesn't redirect to the article NEW action (which makes sense because it's 'render' not 'redirect_to')... so which is the correct scenario?

Comment: sorry, i might have my render/redirect mixed up above. in general you should not `render` in anything except a GET request, so if you are CREATEing, PUTing, PATCHing or DELETE-ing, you should redirect to an appropriate GET resource

Comment: it's also important to remember that this entire controller is being instantiated for your request, so its internal objects (instance variables) can be acted upon- `redirect_to` is just a method with some extra rails magic thrown in.

Answer (score 2):

> ... if there is an error in saving a new article, I should render 'new', which **hits the new route**, and renders the form again so I can resubmit after fixing errors.
>
> ... I'm confused because the new route creates a new Article object and sends it to the view, how are errors preserved?

Here is where you are making an incorrect assumption. `render 'new'` does not redirect the user to `your_controller/new` URI. It simply renders `new.html.erb` view. That's why the `new` page will have the current instance variables in your controller.